# ios UISearchBar hide overlay & prevent hiding navigation & tabbar

Tags: ios, overlay, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

two little questions regarding the UISearchBar/SearchDisplayController:

Is it possible to prevent/hide the overlay which appears when a searchbar is clicked?

If the Searchbar is entered, the Tabbar and the NavigationBar of the current Screen disappears (and dont reappear after leaving the SearchBar) - how can i prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to prevent/hide the overlay which appears when a
>   searchbar is clicked?

Why don't you just use a UISearchBar with the current table and not a UISearchDisplayController? One of the main features of the UISearchDisplayController is it's modal type display. With only the UISearchBar, you can search the current view.

Comment: good point - i implemented the functionality of the searchcontroller by my self, no it works. thank you!